# Select random data with ggmap

Tags: r

This code only works for the center coordinates (x=-95.36, y=29.76).  I want to change them and select random data from that area.

Does anyone knows what is happening?

```
#Select random data and connect it
get_googlemap(urlonly = TRUE)
ggmap(get_googlemap())
# markers and paths are easy to access
d <- function(x=-95.36, y=29.76, n,r,a){
    round(data.frame(lon = jitter(rep(x,n), amount = a),
                     lat = jitter(rep(y,n), amount = a)),
                     digits = r)
}
df <- d(n=50,r=3,a=.3)
map <- get_googlemap(markers = df, path = df,, scale = 2)
ggmap(map)
ggmap(map, extent = "device") +
geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat), data = df, size = 3, colour = "black") +
      geom_path(aes(x = lon, y = lat), data = df)
```

Comment: You need to pass new  values for `x` and `y`  arguments in function `d`, `df1 <- d(x=-90,y=30,n=50,r=3,a=.3)` and read `?set.seed` and `?sample` to select random co-ordinates from a set

Comment: I changed d and df, but it still ubicates the center coordinate in houston,texas.